# Character encoding compatibility between python2 and python3

Tags: python, xml, character-encoding, plist, elementtree

I am writing plist files using ElementTree, and I need to prepend two lines of text before the tree starts, to match Apple's plist syntax.  The following code works in python 2.7, but it fails in python 3.6 with `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('com.input.plist')
with open('com.new.plist', 'w') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">\n')
    tree.write(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

To get this working on python3, I can change it like so:

```
tree = ET.parse('com.input.plist')
with open('com.new.plist', 'w') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">\n')
    tree.write(f, encoding='unicode')
```

But this fails in python2 with `LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode`.  How can I make this compatible with both versions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I open the file in binary mode, then use string.encode() before writing.

```
with open('com.new.plist', 'wb') as f:
    xml_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">\n'
    f.write(xml_header.encode())
    tree.write(f)
```